# How to make a widget on the top / over others in Andorid?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to put a widget on the top of the others ?

The real purpose of this is making a button visible when the softInputKeyboard appears. This button must always be just over the softKeyboard, wherever the scrollBar is.

So maybe there is an other solution to reach the goal, ask for precision, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

LinearLayout prevents this from happening and places the widgets in horizontal/vertical order.

Comment: Obviously. I'll figure out the following. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1) soft keyboard hidden 
[image]

2)soft keyboard visible 
[image]

ANDROID MANIFEST: 
(add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity tag)

```
<activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:name="._TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

XML:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RandomText"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Ok" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And here is the implementation ahah. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I have same requirement but here i'm working with fragments. is it possible same in Fragments?